# How to place the caret at the end in CKEditor 4?

Tags: ckeditor

I'd like to place the caret at the end of the text after `focus()`.

There are a lot of solutions for CKEditor 3, I tried around three of them, but they don't seem to work for CKEditor 4.

Note: I'm using inline-editing with `contenteditable="true"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job (it WFM on themed and inline editors):

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable', {
    on: {
        focus: function( evt ) {
            setTimeout( function() {
                var editor = evt.editor,
                    range = editor.createRange();

                range.moveToElementEditEnd( editor.editable() );
                range.select();
                range.scrollIntoView();
            }, 100 );
        }
    }
} );
```

Note that the timeout is required because on focus selection is automatically placed at the beginning or in place which was clicked, so you need to wait a while to overwrite that behaviour. You can check shorter timeouts of course.

Comment: Great, that works very nice! I tried to put it into `instanceReady()`, right after calling `editor.focus()`, is there any reason why I shouldn't do that? It seems to work fine, at least in Chrome 25...

Comment: Do you mean putting `editor.focus()` inside `editor#instanceReady` listener? It should be ok. If you'll encounter any troubles, then short setTimeout should help :). You can also add `editor#focus` listener inside `editor#instanceReady`, but you'll make it unnecessarily long.